# php script to change button class if page opened

Tags: php, html, css, class, button

I'm trying to get this script working, but unfortunately nothing to do...
I also think there is a better way to do that, but dunno which?

So I want that on an opened page the button remains as it was on hover, so I created a class that looks like the button hover and said the php to apply this class if the current pagename corrispond to the "this button" link.

```
$currentpath = basename(__FILE__);
```

is setted on each page before I include header.php

Thank you!

PHP and HTML:

```
<?h
$o = "/ita/o.h";
$ = "/ita/.h";
$a = "/ita/a.h";
$s = "/ita/s.h";
$st = "/ita/st.h";
$p = "/ita/p";
$t = "/ita/t";
$c = "/ita/c";
?>

<div id="button"> 
  <ul> 
    <li><a href=<?=$o?> class="<?php if($currentpath == basename($o)){echo("buttonon");} ?>">o</a></li>
    <li><a href=<?=$p?> class="<?php if($currentpath == basename($p)){echo("buttonon");} ?>">p</a></li>
    <li><a href=<?=$a?> class="<?php if($currentpath == basename($a)){echo("buttonon");} ?>">a</a></li>
    <li><a href=<?=$s?> class="<?php if($currentpath == basename($s)){echo("buttonon");} ?>">s</a></li>
    <li><a href=<?=$st?> class="<?php if($currentpath == basename($st)){echo("buttonon");} ?>">st</a></li>
    <li><a href=<?=$p?> class="<?php if($currentpath == basename($p)){echo("buttonon");} ?>">p</a></li>
    <li><a href=<?=$t?> class="<?php if($currentpath == basename($t)){echo("buttonon");} ?>">t</a></li>
    <li><a href=<?=$c?> class="<?php if($currentpath == basename($c)){echo("buttonon");} ?>">c</a></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#button ul { 
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0; 
        list-style-type: none; 
        text-align: center; 
        background-color: #F00;
} 
#button ul li {  
        display: inline; 
} 
#button ul li a { 
        display:inline-block;
        color:#FFF;
        font-family:Calibri;
        font-size:18px;
        font-weight:bold;
        padding:4px 15px 4px 15px;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-variant:small-caps;
} 
#button ul li a:hover { 
        background-color:#F00;
        color:#02346F;
        padding:4px 15px 4px 15px;
        font-size:18px;
        font-weight:bolder;
}

.buttonon { 
        background-color:#F00;
        display:inline-block;
        font-family:Calibri;
        font-size:18px;
        font-weight:bold;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-variant:small-caps;
        color:#02346F;
        padding:4px 15px 4px 15px;
        font-size:18px;
        font-weight:bolder;
}
```

EDIT: I added a definition for $currentpath.

Comment: You forgot to tell us the specific problem.

Comment: `$currentpath` is undefined in your code.

Comment: you do not have any css class "buttonselected".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$currentpath` is defined elsewhere in your code:

Using basename() won't work because you have subdirectories, and basename() doesn't return subdirectories.

you could search for a substring:

```
<?php if(strpos($currentpath, $prezzi) !== false){echo("buttonselected");} ?>
```

Comment: sorry this is the header. I defined $currentpath on the file before include header.php is placed.

I setted 
$currentpath = basename(__FILE__); (with __ (it don't post that)
which is returning the filename
basename($prezzi and the others) is also returning filename.